# Get offset().top of element from the top of the window after being already scrolled within the page

Tags: jquery

Upon page load I use

```
agenda_top = $('#agenda').offset().top;
travel_top = $('#travel').offset().top;
hotel_top =$('#hotel').offset().top;
```

to store position of the main section within the page. and then I use those for navigation. eg. `$('#anchor').animate({ scrollTop: hotel_top }, 'ease');` and `#anchor` is `<body>`.

The issue is that on the page there is an expandable table and with each row expanded the positions I stored initially become inaccurate. I would like to have a function that I could call when I open a row, that would recalculate the offsets. I tried calling the same function I use on page load, but because I am not at the top of the page when I call it the retrieved offsets are wrong.

I somehow need to get the offset of the elements `#travel` and `#hotel` from the top of the document perspective. Is that possible?

Here's some numbers. When the page load the offset().top for `#hotel` is `2637` after I open the row which moves the `#hotel` element even further from top I do  offset().top again but this time it returns `2059` but it should be MORE not less than the original number since the div is now expanded. This is when I'm scrolled within the browser window. But if I manually scroll to the top of the window, then do `hotel_top =$('#hotel').offset().top;` I get `3137` which is the correct nuber, but I dont know hot to get this number while being scrolled within the page..

Comment: How are rows opened?

Comment: each has a .click(function(){...}) binded to them. Which changes a div within the row from display none to block

Comment: $(selector).offset().top; is pretty accurate,  but still, what event or action trigger the scroll over the page?

Comment: Like I said on page load i get the position with `hotel_top =$('#hotel').offset().top;` then to scroll there I use `$('#anchor').animate({ scrollTop: hotel_top }, 'ease');` but I need to recalculate the offset after I open the row and if I just do `hotel_top =$('#hotel').offset().top;` again it doesnt take me to the right place

Answer (score 1):

solved this by taking the scrollbars position into account, so when I expand a div I recalculate the positions like this `position = element.offset().top + $(window).scrollTop();` I am actually not using `window` because it returns 0 for scrollTop() but I have a div that wraps all of the content right after `<body>` and I use that. Works flawlessly.